# Pytube isn't downloading videos

Tags: python, pytube

I have pytube `(pytube==12.0.0)` installed. When I run my code it just does nothing, and then finishes executing. It doesn't give any errors, but it also doesn't download the video. This might have something to do with the fact that I have a filter installed on my computer, I've had issues with that before when using the heroku cli, because it was using a proxy. I haven't been able to find anything on how to fix that though.

My code is:

```
import pytube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SFhwxzfXNc'

youtube = pytube.YouTube(url)

video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution()

video.download('/Downloads')
```

Comment: "it just does nothing, and then finishes executing" What exactly does this mean? Do you see any output? Does it take time or does it go back to the command prompt immediately? Did you check the folder in question? Is `/Downloads` a valid path on your system? (Are you sure? It doesn't look like a path I'd normally expect to exist on either a Windows or Linux-based system.) Also, what do you mean by "a filter"? Are you able to download the video by any other means?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're right, I had to change it to the right file path. Stupid mistake. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake - `video.download('/Downloads')` wasn't the right file path. This is the code that works:

```
import pytube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SFhwxzfXNc'

youtube = pytube.YouTube(url)

video = youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution()

video.download('C:/Users/user1/Downloads')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried?

```
from pytube import YouTube, helpers

proxy_handler = {
    "http": "127.0.0.1:20304",
    'https': '127.0.0.1:20304'
}
helpers.install_proxy(proxy_handler)
```

Source: https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1128

Port should depend on your proxy